# JavaScript Can't retrieve value of options from select drop down

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

OK I have a select object that I am creating and it creates properly with my form when I generate it but when I add in the code to retrieve the value from the select I am getting an error that it is null. The code I am using to get the value pretty cookie cutter to what I've seen here so I am confused. Below is the code for the select with the options and the code to grab the values I'm not seeing the issue any help is greatly appreciated.

```
var tools = document.createElement('select');
tools.id = 'sTools';
tools.name = 'sTools';
form.appendChild(tools);

var option = document.createElement('option');
option.value = '33';
option.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Forge'));
tools.appendChild(option);

option = document.createElement('option');
option.value = '1391';
option.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Workbench'));
tools.appendChild(option);

option = document.createElement('option');
option.value = '1753';
option.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Oven'));
tools.appendChild(option);




var e = document.getElementById("sTools");
var cTool = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine - check the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/johnbk/e33uW/ - Please provide your HTML as well

Comment: Just a btw comment - you can use the notation `var option = new Option('Forge', 33);` as a direct replacement for the first option - no need for the 4 statements that leverage `document.createElement` and `document.createTextNode`. Just create the option and then append it to the parent select element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like: **[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/pupov/4/edit)** ?

```
var form = document.getElementById("form");
var tools = document.createElement('select');
tools.id = 'sTools';
tools.name = 'sTools';
form.appendChild(tools);

var cTool;
var e = document.getElementById("sTools");
var options = [
  ["Forge",     "33"],
  ["Workbench", "1391"],
  ["Oven",      "1753"]
];

for(var i=0; i<options.length; i++){
  var opt = document.createElement('option');
  opt.appendChild( document.createTextNode( options[i][0] ) );
  opt.value = options[i][1];
  tools.appendChild(opt); 
}

tools.onchange = function(){
  cTool = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  alert( cTool );
};
```

Comment: And thanks hadn't thought to just loop it to create the elements cleaned my code up a ton!